# Cleveroad WaveInApp shows error after song completion

Tags: android

I'm trying to using `Cleveroad WaveInApp` in my Application
https://github.com/Cleveroad/WaveInApp everything is working fine as I want but when Song Completed it also stops  `mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener`(which works fine when I removed this code).

When I try to change the song it crashes.
Error :-

> java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.InnerAudioVisualization.stopRendering()' on a null object reference
>                                                                        at com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.DbmHandler.stopRendering(DbmHandler.java:61)
>                                                                        at com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.DbmHandler$2.onCalmedDown(DbmHandler.java:82)
>                                                                        at com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.GLAudioVisualizationView$1.onCalmedDown(GLAudioVisualizationView.java:49)
>                                                                        at com.cleveroad.audiovisualization.GLRenderer.onDrawFrame(GLRenderer.java:87)
>                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1608)
>                                                                        at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1299)

MainContainer.class

```
public class MainContainer extends AppCompatActivity
        implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,
        SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "Friday";
    public static final String isPlay = "isPlay";
    public static final String NOTIFICATION_ACTION = "Notification_Action";
    private static final String VOLUME_BUTTON = "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION";
    SlidingUpPanelLayout slideLayout;
    MusicService mService;
    boolean mBound = false;
    Timer t = new Timer();
    SeekBar seekBar;
    ImageView albumArt;
    ImageView panelAlbumart;
    TextView songname;
    TextView singername;
    TextView seekCurrentDuration;
    TextView seekTotalDuration;
    TextView panelSongname;
    TextView panelSingername;
    ImageView playBtn;
    IntentFilter mIntentFilter;
    RelativeLayout panelHead;
    SeekBar volumeControl;
    AudioManager audioManager;
    AudioVisualization audioVisualization;
    VisualizerDbmHandler vizualizerHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_container);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC); //best practice to set volume control
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        ViewPager vp_pages = findViewById(R.id.vp_pages);
        PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new FragmentAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        vp_pages.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

        mIntentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        mIntentFilter.addAction(isPlay);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(VOLUME_BUTTON);
        mIntentFilter.addAction(NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
        TabLayout tbl_pages = findViewById(R.id.tbl_pages);
        tbl_pages.setupWithViewPager(vp_pages);
        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_red);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_container, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Bind to LocalService
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MusicService.class);
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        unbindService(mConnection);
        mBound = false;
    }

    //    control Volume by Seekbar
    private void volumeControl() {
        volumeControl = findViewById(devil.jarvis.friday.R.id.volume_control);
        audioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
        if (audioManager != null) {
            volumeControl.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
            volumeControl.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        }
        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, i, 0);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        registerReceiver(mReceiver, mIntentFilter);
        init();
        //todo add this when song is played
        audioVisualization.onResume();
        updateUI();
        volumeControl();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        audioVisualization.onPause();
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
        super.onPause();

    }


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private void init() {
        albumArt = findViewById(R.id.musicArt);
        panelAlbumart = findViewById(R.id.slidePanelArt);
        songname = findViewById(R.id.song_name);
        singername = findViewById(R.id.singer_name);
        panelSingername = findViewById(R.id.singer_name_head);
        panelSongname = findViewById(R.id.song_name_head);
        seekCurrentDuration = findViewById(R.id.current_time);
        seekTotalDuration = findViewById(R.id.song_duration);
        playBtn = findViewById(R.id.play);
        panelHead = findViewById(R.id.header);
        slideLayout = findViewById(R.id.sliding_layout);
        audioVisualization = findViewById(R.id.visualizer_view);
    }

    public void updateUI() {
        //Update UI
        t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mBound) {
                    try {
                        setupMusicUI(mService.getCurrentDuration(), mService.getDuration());
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        //
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 0, 1000);

    }

    private void setupMusicUI(int currentDuration, int duration) {
        seekBar.setMax(duration);
        seekBar.setProgress(currentDuration);
    }

    //    code for update song details
    private void updateTextInfo() {
        if (mBound) {
            int pos = mService.getPosition();
            panelSongname.setText(arrayList.get(pos));
            panelSingername.setText(artistName.get(pos));
            songname.setText(arrayList.get(pos));
            singername.setText(artistName.get(pos));
            //update album art with text also
            updateAlbumArt();
            changePlayBtn();
            startEqualiser();
//            try{
//                startEqualiser();
//            }catch (Exception e){
//                //
//            }
        }
    }

    private void setSeekbarTime(int position, int duration) {
        int curr_time_seconds = (position / 1000) % 60;
        int curr_time_minutes = (position / 1000) / 60;
        int dur_time_seconds = (duration / 1000) % 60;
        int dur_time_minutes = (duration / 1000) / 60;
        String current_zero_minutes = "0";
        String current_zero_seconds = "0";
        String duration_zero_minues = "0";
        String duration_zero_seconds = "0";
        if (curr_time_minutes > 9)
            current_zero_minutes = "";
        if (curr_time_seconds > 9)
            current_zero_seconds = "";
        if (dur_time_minutes > 9)
            duration_zero_minues = "";
        if (dur_time_seconds > 9)
            duration_zero_seconds = "";
        seekCurrentDuration.setText(current_zero_minutes + curr_time_minutes + ":" + current_zero_seconds + curr_time_seconds);
        seekTotalDuration.setText(duration_zero_minues + dur_time_minutes + ":" + duration_zero_seconds + dur_time_seconds);
    }


    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(VOLUME_BUTTON)) {
                volumeControl();
            }

            if (intent.getAction().equals(isPlay)) {
                boolean show = intent.getBooleanExtra("showPanel", false);
                if (show) {
                    //show Panel here
                    slideLayout.setPanelState(SlidingUpPanelLayout.PanelState.COLLAPSED);
                    updateTextInfo();
                }
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(NOTIFICATION_ACTION)) {
                int action = intent.getIntExtra("action", 0);
                switch (action) {
                    case 1:
                        changePlayBtn();
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        updateTextInfo();
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        updateTextInfo();
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        audioVisualization.release();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_camera) {
            // Handle the camera action
        } else if (id == R.id.nav_gallery) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_slideshow) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_manage) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_send) {

        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Defines callbacks for service binding, passed to bindService()
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className,
                                       IBinder service) {
            // We've bound to LocalService, cast the IBinder and get LocalService instance
            MusicService.LocalBinder binder = (MusicService.LocalBinder) service;
            mService = binder.getService();
            mBound = true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName arg0) {
            mBound = false;
        }
    };


    public void playBtn(View view) {
        if (mBound) {
            mService.play();
            changePlayBtn();
        }
    }

    private void changePlayBtn() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_pause_button);
            } else {
                playBtn.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_arrow);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
        setSeekbarTime(i, mediaPlayer.getDuration());
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
        mService.changeSeekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
    }

    public void previousBtn(View view) {
        if (mBound) {
            mService.previous();
            updateTextInfo();
        }
    }

    public void nextBtn(View view) {
        if (mBound) {
            mService.next();
            updateTextInfo();
        }
    }

    public void startEqualiser() {
        try {
            vizualizerHandler = VisualizerDbmHandler.Factory.newVisualizerHandler(getApplicationContext(), mediaPlayer);
            audioVisualization.linkTo(vizualizerHandler);

        } catch (Exception e) {
//            TODO change it to snackbar message
            Toast.makeText(mService, "Please Give Mic Permission", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


    public void updateAlbumArt() {

        Glide
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(songThumb.get(musicPosition))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_icon)
                .into(panelAlbumart);
        Glide
                .with(getApplicationContext())
                .load(songThumb.get(musicPosition))
                .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_default_icon)
                .into(albumArt);
    }
}
```

and this is my MusicService.class

```
public class MusicService extends MediaBrowserServiceCompat implements
        MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener,
        AudioManager.OnAudioFocusChangeListener {

    private static final String LOGTAG = "Friday";
    public static int musicPosition;
    public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    Uri u;
    // Binder given to clients
    private final IBinder mBinder = new LocalBinder();
    Notification status;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (intent != null && intent.getExtras() != null && intent.getExtras().containsKey("pos")) {
            musicPosition = intent.getIntExtra("pos", 0);
            if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.reset();
                mediaPlayer.release();

            }
            if (arrayList != null) {
                u = Uri.parse(songPath.get(musicPosition));
                mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            }
            try {
                playSong();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                next();
            }
        }
        if (intent.getAction() != null) {
            if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PREV_ACTION)) {
                previous();
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.PLAY_ACTION)) {
                play();
                sendAction(1);
            } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Constants.ACTION.NEXT_ACTION)) {
                next();
            }
        }
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void playSong() {
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(this);
        mediaPlayer.start();
        showNotification();
    }

    private void sendAction(int action){
        /* 1 for play or pause
         * 2 for next
         * 3 for previous
         */
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(MainContainer.NOTIFICATION_ACTION);
        intent.putExtra("action",action);
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
    public int getPosition() {
        return musicPosition;
    }

    public int getCurrentDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }

    public int getDuration() {
        return mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    }

    public void changeSeekTo(int progress) {
        mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
    }

    /**
     * Class used for the client Binder.  Because we know this service always
     * runs in the same process as its clients, we don't need to deal with IPC.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public MusicService getService() {
            // Return this instance of LocalService so clients can call public methods
            return MusicService.this;
        }
    }


    public void next() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            musicPosition = (musicPosition + 1) % songPath.size();
            u = Uri.parse(songPath.get(musicPosition));
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            playSong();
            sendAction(2);
        }
    }

    public void previous() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
            mediaPlayer.release();
            musicPosition = (musicPosition - 1 < 0) ? songPath.size() - 1 : musicPosition - 1;
            u = Uri.parse(songPath.get(musicPosition));
            mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
            playSong();
            sendAction(3);
        }
    }

    public void play() {
        if (mediaPlayer != null) {
            if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                mediaPlayer.pause();
                showNotification();
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.start();
                showNotification();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return mBinder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAudioFocusChange(int i) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        sendAction(4);
        next();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public BrowserRoot onGetRoot(@NonNull String clientPackageName, int clientUid, @Nullable Bundle rootHints) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadChildren(@NonNull String parentId, @NonNull Result<List<MediaBrowserCompat.MediaItem>> result) {

    }
.
.
.
}
```

I don't know what happened.
Can anybody know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

  There is already mediaPlayer.setOnCompleteListener inside VisualizerDbmHandler. So, for use it in other places you should use setInnerOnCompletionListener method to add own complete listener to VisualizerDbmHandler

  Try do not recreate mediaPlayer but setup new source to it

  **My conclusion is**: As you can see in source code of MediaPlayer - it will call onCompletion in cases that unhandled error appears). So, I think, because of recreating mediaPlayer in time, when you call startEqualizer ( recreate visualizerHandler and link it to visualizer view) inside the method linkTo - library call release to previous visualizerHandler and setup variable audioVisualizer to null, that provide you to calling stopRendering on null reference in case of onCompletion calling during to some error during reset/stop/release of MediaPlayer.

Comment: Okk I think I got it.